# Windows 7 won't boot from GRUB

Tags: boot, grub2, windows

I am trying to set up a machine to dual-boot Windows 7 and Ubuntu. Installed Windows 7 first, all seemed fine. Installed Ubuntu 10.04 (to avoid having unity installed by default, which many people have mentioned to me is annoying).

Now when selecting Windows 7 from the grub menu, it simply blank-screens and the returns to the grub menu.

Below is the results of the boot info script. Have tried running testdisk, and getting it to check the windows boot sector; it says both the boot sector and backup boot sector are OK and match each other.

But if the windows boot sector is fine, why wouldn't the usual "chainloader +1" approach work??

Have also tried checking forums for similar problems, but they mostly seem to be people who have accidently installed grub to the windows partition instead of the MBR - according to the bootinfo script results we haven't made that particular mistake here.

```
                  Boot Info Script 0.60    from 17 May 2011


============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

 => Grub2 (v1.97-1.98) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 
    1 of the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and 
    looks in partition 2 for /boot/grub.
 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       Extended Partition
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7
    Boot sector info:  

sda5: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:   According to the info in the boot sector, sda5 starts 
                       at sector 0. But according to the info from fdisk, 
                       sda5 starts at sector 126.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext2
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info:  
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 10.04.3 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /boot/grub/core.img

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7
    Boot sector info:   No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 7
    Boot files:        /bootmgr /Boot/BCD /Windows/System32/winload.exe

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:   According to the info in the boot sector, sdb1 starts 
                       at sector 0. But according to the info from fdisk, 
                       sdb1 starts at sector 63.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

============================ Drive/Partition Info: =============================

Drive: sda _____________________________________________________________________

Disk /dev/sda: 300.1 GB, 300069052416 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 36481 cylinders, total 586072368 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sda1                  63   217,439,774   217,439,712   5 Extended
/dev/sda5                 126   217,439,774   217,439,649   b W95 FAT32
/dev/sda2         217,439,775   401,753,519   184,313,745  83 Linux
/dev/sda3    *    401,753,520   586,067,264   184,313,745   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS


Drive: sdb _____________________________________________________________________

Disk /dev/sdb: 41.2 GB, 41174138880 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 5005 cylinders, total 80418240 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sdb1                  63    80,405,324    80,405,262   b W95 FAT32


"blkid" output: ________________________________________________________________

Device           UUID                                   TYPE       LABEL

/dev/sda2        626bd315-3ecc-4724-96a4-39f00b5f6331   ext2       L
/dev/sda3        457351F40CFFDE49                       ntfs       C
/dev/sda5        7ED4-1FA1                              vfat       Data
/dev/sdb1        001A-9858                              vfat       Internal 40

================================ Mount points: =================================

Device           Mount_Point              Type       Options

/dev/sda2        /                        ext2       (rw,errors=remount-ro)


=========================== sda2/boot/grub/grub.cfg: ===========================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by /usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  load_env
fi
set default="0"
if [ ${prev_saved_entry} ]; then
  set saved_entry=${prev_saved_entry}
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z ${boot_once} ]; then
    saved_entry=${chosen}
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}

function recordfail {
  set recordfail=1
  if [ -n ${have_grubenv} ]; then if [ -z ${boot_once} ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi
}
insmod ext2
set root='(hd0,2)'
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set 626bd315-3ecc-4724-96a4-39f00b5f6331
if loadfont /usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2 ; then
  set gfxmode=640x480
  insmod gfxterm
  insmod vbe
  if terminal_output gfxterm ; then true ; else
    # For backward compatibility with versions of terminal.mod that don't
    # understand terminal_output
    terminal gfxterm
  fi
fi
insmod ext2
set root='(hd0,2)'
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set 626bd315-3ecc-4724-96a4-39f00b5f6331
set locale_dir=($root)/boot/grub/locale
set lang=en
insmod gettext
if [ ${recordfail} = 1 ]; then
  set timeout=-1
else
  set timeout=10
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 2.6.32-38-generic-pae' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,2)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set 626bd315-3ecc-4724-96a4-39f00b5f6331
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-38-generic-pae root=UUID=626bd315-3ecc-4724-96a4-39f00b5f6331 ro   quiet splash
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-38-generic-pae
}
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 2.6.32-38-generic-pae (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,2)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set 626bd315-3ecc-4724-96a4-39f00b5f6331
    echo    'Loading Linux 2.6.32-38-generic-pae ...'
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-38-generic-pae root=UUID=626bd315-3ecc-4724-96a4-39f00b5f6331 ro single 
    echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-38-generic-pae
}
### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###
menuentry "Memory test (memtest86+)" {
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,2)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set 626bd315-3ecc-4724-96a4-39f00b5f6331
    linux16 /boot/memtest86+.bin
}
menuentry "Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)" {
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,2)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set 626bd315-3ecc-4724-96a4-39f00b5f6331
    linux16 /boot/memtest86+.bin console=ttyS0,115200n8
}
### END /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
menuentry "Windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/sda3)" {
    insmod ntfs
    set root='(hd0,3)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set 457351F40CFFDE49
    chainloader +1
}
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

=============================== sda2/etc/fstab: ================================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid -o value -s UUID' to print the universally unique identifier
# for a device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name
# devices that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=626bd315-3ecc-4724-96a4-39f00b5f6331 /               ext2    errors=remount-ro 0       1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

=================== sda2: Location of files loaded by Grub: ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)

 125.679679394 = 134.947528192  boot/grub/core.img                             2
 125.573421001 = 134.833434112  boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1
 125.532954693 = 134.789983744  boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-38-generic-pae          3
 125.523200512 = 134.779510272  boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-38-generic-pae             2
 125.532954693 = 134.789983744  initrd.img                                     3
 125.523200512 = 134.779510272  vmlinuz                                        2
```

Answer (score 1):

If Windows has any issues like hibernation or needing chkdsk, it often will not boot from grub.

If you resized from the Ubuntu installer the Windows boot sector needs repairs which chkdsk will do. But you can only run chkdsk from Windows or a Windows repairCD.

A few have been able to use f8 from grub boot, but it is so quick that it usually does not work. 
There also are third party Windows tools that may be able to run chkdsk if you do not have the Windows repairCD. You should have repair tools CD or flash drive for the current version of every system you have installed.

Also has chkdsk and some other Windows repairs in free version:

http://www.partitionwizard.com/features.html

May be able to run chkdsk from Hiren's boot CD. (mini xp.)
Hiren's Boot CD, and do a chkdsk on the XP

EASEUS Partition Master

http://www.partition-tool.com/personal.htm

Answer (score 0):

insert your windows 7 disk and choose `Repair your computer` and then `startup repair`.
the windows seven bootmenu will be installed then add your ubuntu with `easyBCD` to windows 7 bootloader.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `/Boot/BCD` to `/boot/BCD` I think case counts.